# Lexicographically sort sequences of integers with LINQ

Tags: linq, sorting

I'm trying to find an elegant way to lexically sort sequences of integers with LINQ. In other words, If I have these sequences of ints

- 7, 10, 12, 14, 15
- 10, 12, 15
- 10
- 7, 15
- 14, 15

I would hope to have them come out sorted like this

- 7, 10, 12, 14, 15
- 7, 15
- 10
- 10, 12, 15
- 14, 15

It is the same basic idea of sorting strings by their characters except I want to sort a sequence of ints instead. I don't want to sort alphabetically, but I do want the sequences lexically sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kind of sort you want is known as a [lexical sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order):

> Given two partially ordered sets A and B, the lexicographical order on
>   the Cartesian product A × B is defined as (a,b) ≤ (a′,b′) if and only
>   if a < a′ or (a = a′ and b ≤ b′).

.Net gives you the tools to specify what kind of comparison you want when you want to sort. There are two structures to control this: [`IComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer(v=vs.110).aspx) and the [`Comparison<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx) delegate. You can pass either one of these to `List.Sort`. Example:

```
var lists = new List<Int32[]> {
    new [] { 7, 10, 12, 14, 15 },
    new [] { 7, 15 },
    new [] { 7, 15 },
    new [] { 10 },
    new [] { 10, 12, 15 },
    new [] { 14, 15 } };

lists.Sort((a, b) => {
    var result = a.Zip(b, Tuple.Create)
                  .Select(t => t.Item1.CompareTo(t.Item2))
                  .FirstOrDefault(c => c != 0);
    return result == 0 && !a.Any() ? -1 : result; // Empty list minimum
});
```

([Download for LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/btrmxe.linq))

This passes a `Comparison<Int32[]>` delegate which [zips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) the comparands, allowing element by element comparison and stops comparing when the first non-zero integer comparison is detected. If no unequal elements are found, it returns the default for `Int32` which is 0, meaning the lists are lexicographically equal.

(Note I added another element to your set of lists to show that equal lists of integers sort correctly.)

---

*Bonus chatter:*

I thought this method would be faster than allocating strings and using `OrderBy` but after profiling there's no appreciable difference in speed. I tried to make it faster using a `struct` instead of `Tuple`, which did help a little, and probably saved GC allocation and memory usage, but I didn't measure memory usage performance. If performance is a concern, you'd probably end up eschewing the tidy Linq approach and write the `Comparer` using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the numbers to strings, pad them all to the same length and join the together, then order that, and finally split them up again.

```c#
var intLists = new List<List<int>>
{
    new List<int> { 7, 10, 12, 14, 15 },
    new List<int> { 10, 12, 15 },
    new List<int> { 10 },
    new List<int> { 7, 15 },
    new List<int> { 14, 15 },
};

var orderedLists = intLists
    .Select(l => string.Join("", l.Select (x => x.ToString().PadLeft(10))))
    .OrderBy(l => l)
    .Select(l => l.Split(new [] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select (x => int.Parse(x)));
```

Comment: Brilliant. The padding is the key. I ended up with something like this: `intLists.OrderBy(l => l.Aggregate("", (str, i) => str + i.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0')));`. My integers represented ages of children, so I only had to pad two digits, and even though it worked padding with spaces, I padded with zero to make things more obvious for myself.

Comment: Glad it worked. I padded with spaces to allow for the number `0` but I'm not sure it's needed.